# Prove that planar graph with girth at least 6 contains a vertex of degree at most 2.

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

I'm trying to prove that planar graph with girth at least 6 contains a vertex of degree at most 2.

However, I'm not sure how would I do so. Could you please help me?

Comment: What is the circumference of a graph? (do you mean *girth*, the length of a shortest cycle?) And do you mean degree $2$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Sorry, I mistype the question initally. Is it understandable now?

Comment: If you know the girth, you can bound the number of edges: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2190221/prove-the-following-theorem-if-g-is-a-planar-graph-with-p-vertices-q-edg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Euler's formula for plane graphs,
$$ v+f=e+2.$$
If each vertex has degree $\ge 3$, then $2e\ge 3v$. By the assumption about the girth, each face has at least $6$ edges, so $2e\ge 6f$. Thus
$$ 12=6v+6f-6e\le 4e+2e-6e=0,$$
contradiction.